# Erro ao criar migration(entity framework) após alterar provider do .NET Identity de SQL Server para PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, postgresql, entity-framework

Erro ao criar migration(entity framework) após alterar provider de SQL Server para PostgreSQL em aplicação .NET Identity

Boa tarde pessoal, espero que estejam bem, gostaria de uma ajuda com um erro ao gerar a migration no entity framework.
Tenho um projeto novo criado, usando Blazor e Identity, e gostaria de alterar o provider do Identity de SQL Server para PostgreSQL.
Já alterei o provider e a string de conexão, mas ao executar os comandos para gerar a migração recebo uma mensagem de erro genérica no console.

Erro gerado ao executar o comando add-migration no console:

```
PM> add-migration 20230411_initial -verbose
Using project 'DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server'.
Using startup project 'DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\victor.canos\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages" --runtimeconfig C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\victor.canos\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\7.0.4\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add 20230411_initial --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.dll --project C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.csproj --startup-assembly C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.dll --startup-project C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.csproj --project-dir C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server\ --language C# --configuration Debug --working-dir C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus --root-namespace DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server --nullable
Using assembly 'DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server'.
Using startup assembly 'DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server'.
Using root namespace 'DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\victor.canos\source\repos\DataValue.Blazor.Maximus\Server\'.
Remaining arguments: .
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server'...
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server'...
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL'.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server'...
No design-time services were found.
Reusing namespace of type 'CreateIdentitySchema'.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Initialize(ColumnOperation columnOperation, IColumn column, RelationalTypeMapping typeMapping, Boolean isNullable, IEnumerable`1 migrationsAnnotations, Boolean inline)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.InitializeColumnHelper(ColumnOperation columnOperation, IColumn column, Boolean inline)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(IColumn source, IColumn target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(ITable source, ITable target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
using DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.Models;
using Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(
            DbContextOptions options,
            IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // PostgreSQL uses the public schema by default - not dbo.
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //Rename Identity tables to lowercase
            foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                var currentTableName = modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name).Metadata.GetDefaultTableName();
                modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name).ToTable(currentTableName.ToLower());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.Data;
using DataValue.Blazor.Maximus.Server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

//builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
//.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Estou tentando alterar o provider do .NET Identity, que vem configurado para utilizar o SQL Server, para utilizar o PostgreSQL.

Alterei o provider e a string de conexão, mas ao executar o comando add-migration para atualizar o banco de dados, recebo um erro no console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde pessoal,
depois de várias tentativas, deletei os arquivos de migration gerados anteriomente, junto do snapshot, limpei e recompilei a solução, e deletei todas as tabelas criadas nas migrations anteriores.
Depois desses passos, o add-migration e o update-database funcionaram normalmente e toda estrutura foi recriada.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).